# Angular 9 project fails

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

Angular 9 project fails 
Trying to compile code that works in Angular 8.

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
>   ../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
>   ../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/event_emitter.d.ts(8,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
>   ../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/query_list.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
>   ../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
>   ../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
>   ../../../node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/jsonp_backend.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
>   ../../../node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.
>   ../../../node_modules/@angular/http/src/http.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs'.

I isolate the problem to a service that I am loading.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, takeUntil, tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as Global from './global';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "f202",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Also tried the usual mixture of upgrading typescript, rxjs and angular components.

Any help would be appreciated!

------------------UPDATE-------------

Yes @phix was entirely correct with this second comment, It was still version 7.
I assumed going a global update (*npm install @angular/cli@9.0.0 -g* ) to 9 and then creating a project will automatically create a version 9 project - wrong assumption.

I used the info to properly upgrade my project
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/upgrade-to-angular-9-within-10-minutes-671c6fd6174b

Comment: Try deleting your node_modules folder and re-install

Comment: @phix, I tried that, no joy.

Comment: What's the output of `ng --version`?  You say "Angular 9" but all your deps are v7